# Why does alert() fire but not console.log() for this jQuery in Greasemonkey example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, console, firebug

For this test Greasemonkey UserScript, the alerts pop up but nothing is logged to the Firebug console.
This is with Greasemonkey 0.9.18 and Firebug 1.9.1 in Firefox 12.0.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           test
// @namespace      tester12354
// @include        *
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function($) {
    $.fn.tester1 = function(test) {
        alert(test);
        console.log(test);
    }
}(jQuery));


$.extend({
    tester2: function(test) {
        alert(test);
        console.log(test);
    }
});

alert($().jquery)
console.log($().jquery) 

$().tester1('from tester1');
$.tester2('from tester2');
```

Comment: Just tested it on Google Chrome and it seems to work jQuery version 1.7.2:
http://jsfiddle.net/2k4wh/ Also works in Firefox 10.0

Comment: Additional information: works in jQuery v1.2.6 to v1.7.2 . Firebug version? Firefox version?

Comment: What version of jQuery, Firefox and Firebug are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you are not applying a filter to the console? By just showing Errors or Warnings?

Comment: Does the console still normally log if you type `console.log('test')` into firebug directly?

Comment: Version information added to question.  The console is on the "All" filter.  console.log('test') prints to the console correctly.  I've also tried window.console.log() without success.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Scriptish?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've updated the question to show *exactly* what I'm doing.  It's strange because during my recent testing it actually printed to the console 1 out of about 25 runs.  Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is explained in the [GreaseMonkey manual](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow), in GreaseMonkey scripts, the global context for the script is not the Browser's real window object (unlike in actual scripts that execute on the page) but a dummy version of the window object with the same APIs.

The `console` object is a global variable on the real window and is thus not accessible from GreaseMonkey (or at least from jQuery on GreaseMonkey).

See this page for explanation on what's up with `console` under GreaseMonkey and how you should log messages from GreaseMonkey.

Comment: BTW - its likely that your logs end up on the internal Firefox console - hit CTRL+SHIFT+K to open the built-in console.

Comment: Thanks Guss.  They were indeed showing up in the Firefox console.  I also tried Scriptish as they target Firebug if available.  https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/wiki/console  But it doesn't seem to work with the versions I'm running.  I've created a bug report.  https://scriptish.lighthouseapp.com/projects/83146-firefox-extension/tickets/614-scriptish-not-logging-to-firebug-console

Answer (score 1):

If the page itself doesn't have any `<script>` tags it could be because of the [stupid way in which Firebug injects the console object](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4978).